# How can I get that result from CASE statament in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT field_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN field_name is not null  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count from table_name group by department


RESULT IS:

field_name    count 

AAA              9
BBB              0
CCC              7
```

But how can I get only rows which have more that 0 in the second column.

Comment: You have provided not complete query, have you? There should be a `GROUP BY` somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT field_name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN field_name is not null
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END) as count
    from table_name
group by department
  HAVING `count` > 0
```

`HAVING` clause is executed *after* `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` thus you can address aggregating functions

Answer (score 3):

Use `HAVING` clause:

```
  SELECT field_name,
     SUM(CASE WHEN field_name IS NOT NULL 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count` 
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY department
  HAVING `count` > 0
```

<sub>I think you are selecting `department` instead of `field_name` or you need to group by `field_name`</sub>

Comment: OP provided not a complete query, your query looks odd ;-)

Comment: Your answer is ok.Sorry i can not accept more than one answer.so +1 for u

Answer (score 1):

try belows.

```
SELECT field_name, SUM(CASE WHEN field_name is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count 
from table_name
where field_name is not null
```

actually, second query is good to understand, but first query is better :)

```
SELECT field_name, SUM(CASE WHEN field_name is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count 
from table_name
where SUM(CASE WHEN field_name is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: Your answer is ok.Sorry i can not accept more than one answer.so +1 for u

Comment: sorry, my browser cut the column your code :( after 
    group by department
HAVING is better query :)
good luck!